# How to pair up event participants?

Tags: civievent

My event has a structure of all participants pairing up in study couples (2 or 3 people together).
I know I can create a relationship for each one, but I need to see the pairs very clearly in the event participant list.
How can I show the list of participants grouped by pairs, or even have each 2 (or more) coupled participants highlighted in different colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get somewhat close to your desired functionality by putting the contacts in a smart group and displaying them within the relationship report.

1. Use the advanced search to display all contacts within the event (by adjusting the search fields within ("Events").
2. Add all the contacts to a new [smart group](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/smart-groups/).
3. Create a new report to show relationships (Administer > CiviReport > Create new report from template > Relationship report).
4. In "Filters", set "Group" to your smart group.
5. Adjust other report settings as necessary.

But I suspect the end result will still not be 100% satisfying. Groups of three might not display well enough for you.

Comment: Great, thank you.
And now the only thing missing is to add to this report some custom fields that are related to the participants of the event. How can I do this? Because these fields do not appear in this report template's Columns options.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a [custom report](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-report) for this. It will require some PHP coding, but will give you the level of control you seek.

Comment: If you need help creating a custom report, you can hire one of the [CiviCRM experts](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors). My company [Left Join Labs](http://leftjoinlabs.com) is on that list and you can reach me at sean (at) leftjoinlabs (dot) com.